# How find values in an array that meet two conditions using Python

Tags: python, find, numpy

I have an array

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and I want to find the indices of the element s that meet two conditions i.e.

```
a>3 and a<8
ans=[3,4,5,6]
a[ans]=[4,5,6,7]
```

I can use `numpy.nonzero(a>3)` or `numpy.nonzero(a<8)`
but not
`numpy.nonzero(a>3 and a<8)` which gives the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

When I try to use `any` or `all` I get the same error.
Is it possible to combine two conditional tests to get the ans?

Comment: why you needs numpy, you can't do it like this way            !  filter(lambda a: 3 < a < 8, a)

Comment: @shahjapan - likely because they need the increased speed of a numpy array because they probably really have a much *much* larger dataset.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
numpy.nonzero((a > 3) & (a < 8))
```

& does an element-wise boolean and.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative (which I ended up using) is `numpy.logical_and`:

```
choice = numpy.logical_and(np.greater(a, 3), np.less(a, 8))
numpy.extract(choice, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use numpy array, you can directly use '`&`' instead of '`and`'.

```
a=array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
a[(a>3) & (a<8)]
ans=array([3,4,5,6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Side note, this format works for any bitwise operation.

```
numpy.nonzero((a > 3) | (a < 8)) #[or]
numpy.nonzero((a > 3) & (a < 8)) #[and]
```