# Efficient thresholding filter of an array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filtering, threshold

I need to filter an array to remove the elements that are lower than a certain threshold. My current code is like this:

```py
threshold = 5
a = numpy.array(range(10)) # testing data
b = numpy.array(filter(lambda x: x >= threshold, a))
```

The problem is that this creates a temporary list, using a filter with a lambda function (slow).

As this is quite a simple operation, maybe there is a numpy function that does it in an efficient way, but I've been unable to find it.

I thought that another way to achieve this could be sorting the array, finding the index of the threshold and returning a slice from that index onwards, but even if this would be faster for small inputs (and it won't be noticeable anyway), it's definitively asymptotically less efficient as the input size grows.

**Update**: I took some measurements too, and the sorting + slicing was still twice as fast as the pure python filter when the input was 100.000.000 entries.

```py
r = numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, 100000000)

%timeit test1(r) # filter
# 1 loops, best of 3: 21.3 s per loop

%timeit test2(r) # sort and slice
# 1 loops, best of 3: 11.1 s per loop

%timeit test3(r) # boolean indexing
# 1 loops, best of 3: 1.26 s per loop
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`b = a[a>threshold]` this should do

I tested as follows:

```
import numpy as np, datetime
# array of zeros and ones interleaved
lrg = np.arange(2).reshape((2,-1)).repeat(1000000,-1).flatten()

t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
flt = lrg[lrg==0]
print datetime.datetime.now() - t0

t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
flt = np.array(filter(lambda x:x==0, lrg))
print datetime.datetime.now() - t0
```

I got

```
$ python test.py
0:00:00.028000
0:00:02.461000
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

Comment: This kind of indexing does not maintain the size of the array, how is it possible to keep the same number of elements and zeroing the subthreshold values?

Comment: @linello, a[a<=threshold] = 0 is going to mask out the part that do not exceed the threshold

Comment: I ran in to the issue of filtering based on two criteria. Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3248599/1373468

Comment: @yosukesabai Is it possible to do exactly this, without actually changing the original values. If `np.ma` is meant to do that, I cannot figure out how.

Comment: @embert, not sure what you mean by "changing original values".  The array `lrg` is not changed, and `flt` has all of values that i wanted (anything but zero)

Comment: @yosukesabai Was referring to your comment `a[a<=threshold] = 0`. As I figured now, the same can be achieved using `np.ma.masked_where(a<=threshold, a)`, without zeroing but masking those values which are `<=threshold`

Comment: What to do if we have float array. And we want to compare this array with float threshold?

Comment: @GusevSlava , i don't think it makes any difference, you can still use b = a[a>threshold], where a is array of float, threshold is float

Comment: @yosukesabai For example, for such comparison `0.1 == 0.1` we don't know exactly the result because of floating point. We have to use special numpy functions such as `isclose`. And as the result we can't compare floats in the way `a > b` if i understand correctly.

Comment: I was thinking `>` comparison only.   if you use isclose(), it is going to be `b = a[isclose(a, target)]` .

Comment: @GusevSlava basically all you need is that expression in bracket should give True/False for each element, that's all needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to get the indices where the condition is True and use advanced indexing.

```py
import numpy as np
b = a[np.where(a >= threshold)]
```

One useful function of `np.where` is that you can use it to replace values (e.g. replace values where the threshold is not met). While `a[a <= 5] = 0` modifies `a`, `np.where` returns a new array with the same shape only with some values (potentially) changed.

```py
a = np.array([3, 7, 2, 6, 1])
b = np.where(a >= 5, a, 0)       # array([0, 7, 0, 6, 0])
```

---

It's also very competitive in terms of performance.

```py
a, threshold = np.random.uniform(0,1,100000000), 0.5

%timeit a[a >= threshold]
# 1.22 s ± 92.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit a[np.where(a >= threshold)]
# 1.34 s ± 258 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```