# Get the three minimum values of an array in Python, ignoring a value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have the following array:
`a = [4, -5, 10, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4]`

To get the three minimum values index I do:

```
a1 = np.array(a) 
print a1.argsort()[:3]
```

This outputs the following, which is ok:

> [1 6 0]

The thing is that this includes that `-5` (index `1`).

How can I do this exact thing but ignoring the `-5` of the array?

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994394/efficient-thresholding-filter-of-an-array-with-numpy

Comment: You want to filter out `-5` specifically, or negative numbers, or the second element of `a`? What is your criterion exactly for excluding `-5`?

Comment: Filter out `-5` as I told in the post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should just do the filtering of unwanted values beforehand ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out your specific number after `argsort`:

```
>>> a = [4, -5, 10, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4]
>>> a1 = np.array(a) 
>>> indices = a1.argsort()
>>> indices = indices[a1[indices] != -5]
>>> print(indices[:3])
[6 0 3]
```

It's easy to change your condition. For instance, if you want to filter out all *negative* numbers, then use the following line instead:

```
>>> indices = indices[a1[indices] >= 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to **exclude the minimum element**, you can simply skip the element while slicing:

```
>>> a = [4, 3, 10, -5, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4]
>>> a1 = np.array(a) 
>>> minimum_indexes= a1.argsort()[1:4]
>>> print a1[minimum_indexes]
[0 3 4]
```

Comment: I need a general solution, for next iteration that -5 can be placed in any other position of the array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Borja this *is* a general solution - note that you're skipping the first element of the *index array*, not the unsorted one. I've updated the question with a different full example.

Comment: @Borja Or did you want to ignore `-5` *specifically*, and not the minimum element?

Comment: Yes, exactly goncalopp. I want to ignore `-5` specifically as I told in the post. Thanks in advance.