# How to filter a numpy array based on a field of its elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know that I can use index expressions to filter a numpy array as shown in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7994426).

```
>>> b = a[a>threshold]
```

But, what if I need the logical condition to be based on a field of the array to be filtered? e.g. with:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
>>> arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

When I try to do a similar filter based on the 3rd field/column:

```
>>> b = arr[arr[2]>0]
```

I get an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension
>   0; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 4

I can't get the filtered array. What I need is the same result of the following list comprehension:

```
[r for r in aa if r[2] > 0]
```

with

```
aa =  [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]
```

What is the right way to filter based on a field/column?

Comment: Filter by the second axis to filter by column: `arr[:, arr[2]>0]`.

Comment: @PydPiper and jpp Thanks! You are right.