# append large number to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, append

I have a Xmatrix  of Row=12584 and Col 784. I want to extract each row based on another Tmatrix of Row=12584 Col 1 and append the values to numpy array X1 or X2. Even with smaller row size of 1500 it takes over 10 mins. I am sure there is better and efficient way to extract entire row and append to an array

```
import numpy as np
import time
start_time = time.time()

Row = 12584
#Row = 1500
Col = 784
Xmatrix = np.random.rand(Row,Col)

Tmatrix = np.random.randint(1,3,(Row,1))
X1 = np.array([])
X2 = np.array([])

for i in range(Row):
    if Tmatrix[i] == 1:
        for y in range(Col):
            print ('Current row and col are --', i, y, Xmatrix[i][y])
            X1 = np.append(X1, Xmatrix[i][y])
    else:
        for y in range(Col):
            X2 = np.append(X2, Xmatrix[i][y])

print (X1)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: `alist.append(Xmatrix[i,y])` should be faster.  But either way, iterating on rows and cols is slow.  Even if you iterate on Row and do the test, you don't need to iterate on `Col`,  `alist.extend(Xmatrix[i]` puts the whole row in the list at once.

Comment: @hpaulj - ur suggestion of extend with list is working out - if u could post it as answer I can go ahead and select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
import time
start_time = time.time()

Row = 12584
#Row = 1500
Col = 784
Xmatrix = np.random.rand(Row,Col)

Tmatrix = np.random.randint(1,3,(Row,1))

X1 = Xmatrix[(Tmatrix==1).reshape(-1)]
X2 = Xmatrix[(Tmatrix==2).reshape(-1)]

print(X1.reshape(-1))

print(time.time() - start_time)
```

On my computer the program runs in 0.34 seconds.
When using numpy it is good to avoid loops by indexing and slicing
http://codeinpython.com/tutorials/numpy-array-indexing-slicing/

Comment: Can you please explain "X1 = Xmatrix[(Tmatrix==1).reshape(-1)]" what does it do .. too pythonic for me i guess

Comment: I will explain  "X1 = Xmatrix[(Tmatrix==1).reshape(-1)]"

"reshape(-1)" will flatten the array into an 1d-array 
"Xmatrix[Bool_Array]" returns the rows, where Bool_Array is True.
See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994394/efficient-thresholding-filter-of-an-array-with-numpy 
and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arra

Answer (score 2):

You can drop iteration through columns `for y in range(Col):`, in numpy you can retrieve the whole row by:

```py
Xmatrix[i, :]
```

and then append it by

```py
X1=np.append(X1, [Xmatrix[i, :]], axis=0)
```

or alternatively:

```py
X1=np.vstack([X1, Xmatrix[i, :]])
```

**EDIT**

To make appending work - first you need to create X1 and X2 in the proper shape parameters. In this case:

```py
X1=np.empty(shape=(0, Col))
X2=np.empty(shape=(0, Col))
```

Comment: getting error with append - "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)"                                                                                                        and for vstack getting error "ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 0 and the array at index 1 has size 784

Comment: Small tweak - you need to create X1 and X2 in the predefined shape - see EDIT in my answer.

Comment: Still get below error - "ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 12584 and the array at index 1 has size 784

Comment: Pardon! Now it should work - I used number of rows to create empty list, instead of number of columns...

Answer (score 1):

With lists, this should be fairly efficient:

```
X1 =[]
X2 =[]    
for i in range(Row):
    if Tmatrix[i] == 1:
        X1.extend(Xmatrix[i])
    else:
        X2.extend(Xmatrix[i])
```

You can `np.array(X1)` after if needed.

Comment: @hpaulji - ur solution was most intuitive to me but I see selected answer as best way to do it. Thanks for the help :)